# ubuntu phone - How to transfer photos from phone to ubuntu computer

Tags: ubuntu, phone

I want to transfer my photos from my ubuntu phone to my ubuntu (actually Mint) computer.) I have tried via bluetooth without success. Can you even do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - plug it into a USB port and it should show up as a mounted device.

(Worked on mint 17)